# Blender GPU compute render preview crash

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have an issue with Blender that makes the application crash after rotating and zooming in 3D (middle mouse button/rotate view button). It crashes in roughly 30 seconds or in-between after doing that resulting in a “Not Responding” text at the top of the screen. Waiting doesn’t do justice, and if I render preview with my CPU instead it works perfectly fine, but it’s a lot slower.

I’m using Cycles to render preview and I don’t know much about the settings as I am a beginner.

I opened up a project file made from Blender (the one with the BMW model) and it seemed to work fine, so maybe it’s something with the project I am working on?

Please if you know anything about why it crashes I would be extremely grateful to know what’s causing this, I want to continue the project. I can send any information needed regarding the project to help fix this, thank you!

Specs:

-Blender 2.8

-NVidia GeForce GTX 1080 8GB

-Intel i7-6700k 4.00GHz

-16GB RAM

[image]

Comment: are your drivers for the graphics card up to date?

Comment: Yes! I was thinking that as well, and guess what? It doesn't crash anymore.